# JPA named query | Could not extract resultset

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I am newbie in JPA tech stack. I am facing problem in implementing single JPA native query for update and select.

```
 @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true) 

    @Query(value =   "UPDATE stories s "
                    + "SET rank = :reorderPosition" 
                    + " WHERE id = :selectedStory ;" 
                    + "UPDATE stories s "
                    + "SET rank = rank+1"
                    + " WHERE rank >= :reorderPosition "
                    + "AND id <> :selectedStory ;"
                    +"SELECT id " +
                       "FROM stories s  " +
                       "WHERE s.epic_Id = :epicId " + 
                       "ORDER BY rank", nativeQuery = true) 
    List<Integer> reorder(@Param("selectedStory") int selectedStory, @Param("reorderPosition") int reorderPosition,@Param("epicId") int epicId);
```

This is giving error "Could not extract resultset"

If I break my query into two parts , its working perfectly.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true) 

    @Query(value =   "UPDATE stories s "
                    + "SET rank = :reorderPosition" 
                    + " WHERE id = :selectedStory ;" 
                    + "UPDATE stories s "
                    + "SET rank = rank+1"
                    + " WHERE rank >= :reorderPosition "
                    + "AND id <> :selectedStory ;"
                    , nativeQuery = true)
void reorder(@Param("selectedStory") int selectedStory, @Param("reorderPosition") int reorderPosition); 


 @Query(value =
            "SELECT id " +
                   "FROM Story s  " +
                   "WHERE s.epicId = :epicId " + 
                   "ORDER BY rank")
List<Integer> getStoriesIDBySortOrder(@Param("epicId") int epicId);
```

Please suggest how can I implement in single query and also please refer some good websites to study JPA named query.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `@Query` and `@Param` are from the Spring Data project?

Comment: yes @wabi you are right

Comment: Well, what you want to achieve is not possible AFAIK - mapping two JPQL queries onto one method. This needs to be solved differently - either by implementing the DAO method yourself, in which you can call as many queries as you want. But that is not so simple in Spring Data if you are new to JPA stack. So, if you insist on using Spring Data (which si great, but maybe not so great when you are trying to learn something this complex), just have two methods and then on upper layer of your architecture call them. Or do the reordering in memory. What is best approach depends on many things...

Comment: Thanks @Wabi for detailed explanation.